# Strange segfault in unique_ptr

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, unique-ptr

After a small modification in my code I encountered a segfault while running it and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code working :

```
std::shared_ptr<UCHAR> myClass::myMethod(const char *str)
{
    size_t strLen = strlen(str);
    ULONG paddedLen = (strLen % this->bufferLen)
        ? ((strLen / blockSize) + 1) * this->bufferLen
        : strLen;

    std::unique_ptr<UCHAR> padded = std::make_unique<UCHAR>(paddedLen);
    memset(padded.get(), 0, paddedLen);
    memcpy(padded.get(), str, strLen);

    std::unique_ptr<UCHAR> buffer = std::make_unique<UCHAR>(this->bufferLen);
    memcpy(buffer.get(), this->buffer, this->bufferLen);

...
}
```

Here is the code failing :

```
std::shared_ptr<UCHAR> myClass::myMethod(const char *str)
{
    size_t strLen = strlen(str);
    ULONG paddedLen = (strLen % this->bufferLen)
        ? ((strLen / blockSize) + 1) * this->bufferLen
        : strLen;

    std::unique_ptr<UCHAR> padded = std::make_unique<UCHAR>(paddedLen + 1); <-- Added +1 here
    memset(padded.get(), 0, paddedLen + 1);  <--Added +1 here
    memcpy(padded.get(), str, strLen);

    std::unique_ptr<UCHAR> buffer = std::make_unique<UCHAR>(this->bufferLen);  <---Crashes here
    memcpy(buffer.get(), this->buffer, this->bufferLen);

...
}
```

The only difference is I added a +1 when alloccating padding and memsetting it.

It crashes when making the second unique pointer.

Does anything seems wrong with my code / te way I am using the unique_ptr ?

For informations : compiled on Windows using QMake with Mingw 7.3.0 32-bit

Comment: Did you mean to use `make_unique<UCHAR[]>`? `make_unique<T>` makes a single `T` and `make_unique<T[]>(n)` makes an array of `T` with size `n`.

Comment: Right. `std::unique_ptr<UCHAR> padded = std::make_unique<UCHAR>(paddedLen);` doesn't allocate space for an array.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh yes you're right, I try to use smart pointers more and more to limit the use of raw pointer and haven't use them for arrays before.
Quite surprising the first code sample did work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> std::unique_ptr<UCHAR> padded = std::make_unique<UCHAR>(paddedLen + 1); <-- Added +1 here
> std::unique_ptr<UCHAR> buffer = std::make_unique<UCHAR>(this->bufferLen);  <---Crashes here
> ```

You are allocating *single `UCHAR`s* each time, whose values are `paddedLen + 1` and `this->bufferLen`, respectively.  You want *arrays* whose lengths are `paddedLen + 1` and `this->bufferLen` elements instead.  You need to use the template specializations of `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique()` for arrays, eg:

```cpp
auto padded = std::make_unique<UCHAR[]>(paddedLen + 1);

std::fill_n(padded.get(), paddedLen + 1, 0);
std::copy_n(str, strLen, padded.get());

auto buffer = std::make_unique<UCHAR[]>(this->bufferLen);
std::copy_n(this->buffer, this->bufferLen, buffer.get());

...
```

That being said, this can be simplified using `std::vector` instead:

```cpp
std::vector<UCHAR> padded(paddedLen + 1, 0);
std::copy_n(str, strLen, padded.begin());

std::vector<UCHAR> buffer(this->bufferLen);
std::copy_n(this->buffer, this->bufferLen, buffer.begin());

...
```

Comment: Later on in the function I use some windows libraries needing arrays of Uchar, this is why I used array and not vectors.
Otherwise, yes vectors could really be a better idea.

Comment: A `std::vector` is just a wrapper for a dynamically allocated array.  You can use a `vector`'s array anywhere you are using a `unique_ptr`'s array. You can use the `vector`'s `data()` method to get a pointer to the array, same as you do with the `unique_ptr`'s `get()` method.

Comment: OOh,
I didn't know about that. Great to be learning everyday, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::unique_ptr<UCHAR> padded = std::make_unique<UCHAR>(paddedLen + 1);
memset(padded.get(), 0, paddedLen + 1);  <--Added +1 here
memcpy(padded.get(), str, strLen);
```

Any chance that strLen is greater than paddedLen? If your string is 80 and your bufferLen is 40, then paddedLen is 0, but now you're going to allocate a buffer of length 1 and copy 80 characters to it.